# How to share parameters between different gradle tasks

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build

Let's say I have two gradle tasks: `foo` and `beforeFoo`.

Not a surprise - `beforeFoo` action must be done before `foo` and I have this:

```
task foo << {
    dependsOn 'beforeFoo'
}
```

Than I started to feel that my `beforeFoo` should get some information
which is visible for `foo` and isn't for `beforeFoo` and I need to pass it somehow. Tasks defined in separated .gradle files which are linked together by root **build.gradle** by `apply from` expression.

What I've already tried:

**1**

`foo` and `beforeFoo` defined in different .gradle files and non of them is root, so it's not possible to reuse project.ext.myInformation between tasks

**2**

to make 'beforeFoo' a class extended of `DefaultTask` and create  something like

```
task `beforeFoo` (type: BeforeFooClass){
   myInfo='info'
}
```

no way, BeforeFooClass is not visible if it's defined somewhere not in current .gradle file

Can't believe I cannot easily specify arguement for `a.dependsOn b` expression. I would be so happy if get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not understand the question, but given `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: 'before.foo.gradle'
apply from: 'foo.gradle'
```

and `before.foo.gradle`:

```
task beforeFoo() << {
    println "executing beforeFoo"
    println "value is: " + project.ext.value
}
```

and `foo.gradle` (with separate code for 'configuration' phase and 'execution' phase):

```
task foo(dependsOn: "beforeFoo") {
    println "configuring foo"
    project.ext.value = "is set by foo"
}

foo << {
    println "executing foo"
}
```

Observe this result:

```
bash$ gradle foo
configuring foo
:beforeFoo
executing beforeFoo
value is: is set by foo
:foo
executing foo
```

That is:

- `foo` sets the value in the configuration phase
- `beforeFoo` reports the value in the execution phase
- `foo` prints text in execution phase

Comment: The scope and lifespan of `project.ext` is unclear to me.  For example, what happens if I have another task `bar`, which looks exactly like `foo` but sets `project.ext.value` to another value.  Will `foo` and `bar` clobber the value of `project.ext.value`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following project:

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'beforeFoo.gradle'
apply from: 'foo.gradle'
```

**beforeFoo.gradle**

```
task beforeFoo {
  ext.someValue = foo.someValue
  doLast {
    println someValue
  }
}
```

**foo.gradle**

```
task foo {
  dependsOn 'beforeFoo'
  ext.someValue = "I'm value from foo"
}
```

When you try to execute `foo` task you get the output:

```
$ gradle foo

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'beforeFoo.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'foo' for task ':beforeFoo' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.488 secs
```

For this case you have two options:

1. Use groovy's lazyGString: just add `"{ ->` and `}"` around the property from **foo**:

   `ext.someValue = "${ -> foo.someValue }"`

   See [Closures in GStrings from Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_closures_in_gstrings)
2. Use `afterEvaluate` block in **beforeFoo.gradle**:

   ```
   afterEvaluate {
     task beforeFoo {
       ext.someValue = foo.someValue
       doLast {
         println someValue
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   > **afterEvaluate**(closure)
   >
   > Adds a closure to be called immediately after
   >   this project has been evaluated. The project is passed to the closure
   >   as a parameter. Such a listener gets notified when the build file
   >   belonging to this project has been executed. A parent project may for
   >   example add such a listener to its child project. Such a listener can
   >   further configure those child projects based on the state of the child
   >   projects after their build files have been run.
   >
   > [Gradle's Project API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:afterEvaluate(groovy.lang.Closure))

**The result is:**

```
$ gradle foo
:beforeFoo
I'm value from foo
:foo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.449 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

### build.gradle

```
apply from: 'before.gradle'

task foo {
    dependsOn 'beforeFoo'
    doLast{
        println value
    }
}
```

---

### before.gradle

```
task beforeFoo << {

    println value
}
```

---

### gradle.properties

```
value=MyValue
```